# Create hollow border/square wpf

Tags: wpf, silverlight, wpf-controls

I want to create a control in WPF/Silverlight. This control is rectangle/border which is hollow from the center. My intention is to gray out everything else except for a squared area within the rectangle/border container. Is it possible to do this way?

Also, it should be able to move this hollow area on mouse movement.

Thanks everyone for help in advance. [image: This is the sample output I want]

Comment: what does hollow refer to here?

Comment: Hi David I've added a sample image for reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the easiest solution would be this:

```
<Grid Width="256" Height="256" MouseMove="UIElement_OnMouseMove">
    <Image Source="test1.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
    <Path Fill="#81808080" Stretch="Fill">
        <Path.Data>
            <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Exclude">
                <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                    <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,100,100" />
                </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                    <RectangleGeometry
                        x:Name="Hole"
                        RadiusX="7"
                        RadiusY="7"
                        Rect="20,20,60,60" /> <!-- this is the hole -->
                </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
            </CombinedGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path> 
</Grid>
```

Event handler:

```
private void UIElement_OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    var element = (FrameworkElement) sender;
    var position = e.GetPosition(element);

    var relativeX = position.X/element.ActualWidth*100.0;
    var relativeY = position.Y/element.ActualHeight*100.0;

    Hole.Rect = new Rect(relativeX - 20, relativeY - 20, 40, 40);    
}
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the same I've tried to implement but the problem is that when I want to DataBind "Rect" property of Gemotery2 to mouse movement there seems to be a performance lag. I mean the movement is not smooth. I have created a sample project and link is given below. My intention is to have a smooth movememnt:
http://sdrv.ms/11Ih7HE

Comment: Thanks! movement with your code is very smooth. I am still wondering why for mine it is very sluggish (if we move faster around).